# Passing an java Clock to a controller(mapping class )

Tags: java, exception, servlets, abstract

I have a requirement of passing a java Clock to a controller, but since Clock is an abstract class, it throws an error . It is a web application. I basically do not need the clock object as the controller parameter, but since i initialize the controller in unit tests , the parameter is required. 
Any thoughts ?
basically i am trying to do this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/abc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getRequests(@PathVariable("name") String name, @PathVariable("age") int age, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request, Clock clock) {
    someMethod(clock) //-- for unit testing only
}
```

Getting  a servlet exception.

`Failed to instantiate [java.time.Clock]: Is it an abstract class?`

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Yes clock is an abstract.public abstract class Clock extends Object

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Java Clock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) is an abstract class. You can instantiate Clock in your tests using [FixedClock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#fixed-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-) as follows to pass the your controller

```
Clock fixedClock = Clock.fixed(Instant.now(), ZoneId.systemDefault())
```